# Iphone is able to connect to multiple device via BLE in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on the BLE part. I can connect to 1 peripheral and transfer data is good but now i want to connect to multiple devices at the same time and able to know which device is sending data to my app. Is it possible to do?

My thinking is after pairing to any device, we can create a paired device list with UUID. When receiving or sending data, we will loop the paired device list and get its UUID to know which device is transferring data?

Please give some advice. Thanks so much.

Comment: The relevant CBPeripheral object is passed to your delegate methods when data is read/written

Comment: @Paulw11: As you said, so i need only to save the list of paired device. When the device is read/written data, CBPeripheral can know which device. One more thing, do you know how to allow the app connect to the multiple device in the same time? Thanks

Comment: Just use `[central connect:...]` more than once.

Comment: @Paulw11 I will try your solution. But may I know the maximum number of device able to connected to? And is there any problem when connecting to many device in the same time? Thanks

Comment: @Paulw11: I just wonder that how about the delegate methods when data is read/written by mutliple devices in the same time?

Comment: I don't know if the maximum number of devices is stated anywhere.  You don't have to worry about multiple devices sending data at the same time as long as you process the data in reference to the peripheral that is supplied to your delegate method.

Comment: It seems that I've read somewhere (here?) that an iDevice could connect to 8 devices at the same times, mostly from tests from a user than specified in a doc.